# packery overlapping, layout method does not work properly when adding html elements via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, packery

[Example does not work](http://jsfiddle.net/qA7wL/)

The above link is an example of my problem. When I added some text in a `span` via `ajax`, the `divs` were overlapping.

However if I add text without `ajax`, the `layout` method works. [Example works without `ajax`](http://jsfiddle.net/qA7wL/1/)

Is there any way to re-layout `divs` after adding new elements via `ajax`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is I did not put `layout` inside `complete`.

Now [it](http://jsfiddle.net/qA7wL/2/) works.